# How can I get stack to compile my codebase with clash-ghc?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a Haskell codebase that currently uses Stack for compilation. Unfortunately as far as I can tell Stack only allows me to compile with GHC or GHCJS. I would like to use Stack to compile with [clash-ghc](https://www.stackage.org/package/clash-ghc) which uses GHC as a front end, to generate RTL Circuits (Verilog/VHDL).

Is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Comment: Did you check the [FAQ](https://github.com/clash-lang/clash-compiler/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-run-and-install-clash-using-stack)?

Comment: Yes, the clash-faq details how to use stack to install clash, and how to use it to run clash interactively/from the command line. What it does not do is answer my question, which is how to get stack to use clash instead of ghc or ghcjs when compiling a stack project.